# how to send part of the object to handlebar templating

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I use ajax to get the template.html(i.e data) and render it using .html

```
     showhider = Handlebars.compile(data);
     $('#'+target).html(showhider(wl_data));
```

wl_data is big json! when i render it ! it takes around 1.5s to render the complete template which is quite high hence i want to pass part of the object and then append the full while the user is busy checking out first few objects.

```
     $('#'+target).append(showhider(wl_data));
```

how to send part of the object to render then get the remaining?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without seeing wl_data it's hard to give you an exact answer but you could try:

```
$('#'+target).append(showhider(wl_data.onlyThisObjectArrayStringOrWhaterver));
```